# Meteor 0.9 package publish issue

Tags: meteor, package

As per this https://hackpad.com/Migrating-Packages-zN0we9sIjkH I created a new meteor package and currently facing a problem when trying to publish.

PackageName : 'UserId:packageName'

To add package : 'meteor add packageName' (mateor add UserId:packageName did not work).
Package runs locally without any issue.

When I tried to publish,

`cd path/to/your:package`
`meteor publish`

Message :

> There is no package named 'packageName'. If you are creating a new package, use the --create flag. 
>   Publish failed.

Then I tried "meteor publish --create"

Message :

> To confirm that you wish to create a top-level package with no account
>   prefix, please run this command again with the --top-level option.
>   (Only administrators can create top-level packages without an account prefix)

I used "UserId: PackageName" when creating the package and already log in to meteor account.  Any idea to fix this issue?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the `name` field is in `package.js`:

```
Package.describe({
  name: "user:packagename",
  // other fields
});
```

Then, there will be no need to make sure the package is in a directory with the same name.

See https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status for an example.

Comment: Hi Andrew Thanks. I was missing User in package name. Thanks for the example.

Successfully published: https://atmospherejs.com/prasad19sara/client-debugger